# How do i set the cursor in a html editor using IE (7-8)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, tinymce

Actually i am trying to **set the cursor to a specific node inside a html editor** (which uses a contenteditable iframe). For example i have several paragraphs and want the cursor to move to the start of the previous paragraph.
Unfortunatly, the Internet Explorers range object does not support `setStartBefore` and `setStartAfter`. [The ierange project](http://code.google.com/p/ierange/) is not an option - the solution i am looking for needs to work with IE out of the box.

**How do i set the cursor in IE?**

In Firefox the solution is straight forward:

```
// sets the cursor position (start defines, if cursor is needed at the start or end of the node)
function setCursor(editor, node, start){

var tn = editor.getDoc().createTextNode("."); // gets the editors document
  if (start){
    node.insertBefore(tn, node.firstChild);
  } 
  else node.appendChild(tn);

  rng = editor.selection.getRng();  // gets the browsers range object for the users selection
  rng.selectNode(tn);
  rng.setStartBefore(tn);
  rng.setStartAfter(tn);

  ed.selection.setRng(rng);
  node.removeChild(tn);  // removes the caret node - curser is placed now
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use my [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy) project for this. The code would then be the same in all browsers:

```
function setCursor(element, start) {
    var doc = element.ownerDocument || element.document;
    var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;

    rangy.init();
    var range = rangy.createRange(doc);
    range.selectNodeContents(element);
    range.collapse(start);
    rangy.getSelection(win).setSingleRange(range);
}
```

Alternatively, this particular case isn't too tricky without a library:

```
function setCursor(element, start) {
    var doc = element.ownerDocument || element.document;
    if (typeof doc.createRange != "undefined") {
        var range = doc.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(element);
        range.collapse(start);
        var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
        var sel = win.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (typeof doc.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        var textRange = doc.body.createTextRange();
        if (start) {
            textRange.moveToElementText(element);
            textRange.collapse(start);
        } else {
            var markerEl = doc.createElement("span");
            markerEl.innerHTML = "\u00A0";
            element.appendChild(markerEl);
            textRange.moveToElementText(markerEl);
            element.removeChild(markerEl);
        }
        textRange.select();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, works (tested FF, IE8, Google Chrome). do you know why IE8 sets the cursor at the beginning of the next line when start is false (FF sets it to the end of the current paragraph)?

Comment: It's because IE's TextRange and selection handling stuff is idiosyncratic and annoying. Actually in IE you might need a dummy element. I'll test and amend.

Answer (score 0):

[Working with the Cursor Position](http://parentnode.org/javascript/working-with-the-cursor-position/)
*(This solution works for me in IE, Firefox and Opera)*

Comment: That page is irrelevant because it is dealing specifically with textareas and inputs, not general editable HTML content (which is what the question is about). Also, it's not very good.

Comment: @Tim: you are right, but the approach of setting the cursor could be possibly adapted (+1)